# Reply 2 thread groups one after the other

Tags: jmeter, replay

I have 2 thread groups in one test plan in Jmeter. I know how to replay both the thread groups one after the other during a load test i.e., by selecting 'Run the thread group consecutively' option in the test plan.

But I want to do the same in GUI mode for one iteration. I am fixing the second thread group and want to replay that after the first thread group completes. I checked the option but it didn't worked. Is there any other way?

Here is my Test Plan-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edgkg.jpg)

Comment: You are talking about non-GUI or GUI mode? Normally, your option should work when you have 1 thread 1 loop in both the thread groups and  'Run the thread group consecutively' option checked. If it is not working, then share your plan.

Comment: @sunny_teo Yes I am talking about GUI mode only. Edited my question to add Test Plan.

Comment: Please expand your plan and show view result tree output. Also, confirm your thread group settings.

Comment: @sunny_teo I have disabled the view results tree of one thread group and replayed. So only one thread group was executed. After enabling both the results tree files, the second thread also executed. Thank you for ur time!